# Tailwind dynamic class name used incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

One of the weirdest issues, or problems, that I've been stuck with for an afternoon, and there's no good solution yet, is about `tailwindcss`'s dynamic class names

When I try to code like this:

```js
const RandomWebsite = ({friendlink}) {
const hover_boxShadow =  `hover:shadow-[5px_5px_50px_15px_${friendlink.theme_color}]` 
return <div className = `${hover_boxShadow} w-10 h-10`></div> 
}
```

You know, when I mouse over it, there is no shadow effect. I read the official documentation that concatenated strings are not allowed, so I first used a variable to concatenate the string and inserted `className`. I don't know why it is still not allowed.

So I tried the following: the parent component directly concatenates the string and passes it directly to the child component

```js
const RandomWebsite = ({friendlink, hover_boxShadow}) {
return <div className = `${hover_boxShadow} w-10 h-10`></div> 
}
```

Still can't...
[Reference Link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names)

Given that we can't use **inline styles** with the `:hover` pseudoclass, how do I do that thing

Comment: The full classname has to be written somewhere in the file as far as I know. Just having all possible classnames as complete strings somewhere should work.

Comment: The important thing is that my color is dynamically obtained, from the server, can only do string concatenation, the official does not allow this

Comment: You can just assign all possible string-values to a variable and then dont use the variable, but your dynamically generated string. The values just have to be there, so they will be in the generated css file.

Comment: _Tailwind CSS works by scanning all of your HTML, JavaScript components, and any other template files for class names, then generating all of the corresponding CSS for those styles._ [tailwindcss.com](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths)

Comment: I thought, my color is all given by the user, these characters can't exist, I don't know what other people want to give the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a CSS variable to have a "placeholder" for the value that you fetch at runtime like:

```
const RandomWebsite = ({friendlink}) {
  const hover_boxShadow =  `hover:shadow-[5px_5px_50px_15px_var(--color)]`;

  return (
    <div
      className=`${hover_boxShadow} w-10 h-10`
      style={{ '--color': friendlink.theme_color }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw another solution yesterday. It's more complicated, but it's always good to solve problems, like：

```js
const RandomWebsite = ({friendlink}) {
const themeColor = friendlink.theme_color
const [hoverShadow, setHoverShadow] = useState({})
const handleMouseenter = () => {
    setHoverShadow({boxShadow: `5px 5px 50px 15px ${themeColor}`})
  }
const handleMouseleave = () => {
    setHoverShadow({})
  }
return (
<div onMouseEnter = {handleMouseenter} onMouseLeave = {handleMouseleave} style={hoverShadow}
</div>
)}
```